# How do I refer to data objects in d3.js with different property names?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, d3.js

I'm trying to make some circles in d3.js from a data set where each property has a different name:

```
var h = 500;
var w = 800;
var data = {'Jane' : 30, 'John' : 40, 'Mary' : 50, 'Al' : 60};
var svg = d3.select("body") 
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d;
    });
```

Is there a way to make the radius of the circles correspond to these people's ages without restructuring the data?

Comment: I would highly recommend reformatting the data to make your intent clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the data should be in an array; that is

```
var data = [{'Jane' : 30, 'John' : 40, 'Mary' : 50, 'Al' : 60}]
```

but even the above is not right, because d3 will iterate through all the elements of the array and call the corresponding callbacks; So you have to create an array of n elements.

var data = [{name: jane: , age: 30}, {name: 'John', age: 40}, {name:'Mary', age: 50}, {name: 'Al', age: 60}]

you can write a helper function that will convert your data into the appropriate format:

```
            var h = 500;
            var w = 800;
            var data = convertData({jane: 30 ,  'John': 40 ,  'Mary': 50 ,  'Al': 60 });
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);
            var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function (d) {
                    return d;
                })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {
                    return d;
                })
                .attr("r", function (d) {
                    return d.age;
                });

            function convertData(data) {
                var ret = [];
                for (var prop in data) {
                    ret.push({
                        name: prop,
                        age: data[prop]
                    });
                }

                return ret;
            }
```

You would need to think what you want the cx and cy values be like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/L4Y7t/)**

```
var datanew = [];
$.each(data,function(key,value){
                       datanew.push({
                        name: key,
                        age: value
                                   });
                               });
```